# Emberjs: Define model in Route

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to define a model in ember from a json object that does not conform to the JSON API standard. If I define my Route like

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        var url  = "http://website.com/prequalification";

        return Ember.$.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
            return data.collection.template;
        });
    }
});
```

How do I then access my data in the template. I am trying to avoid writing a custom adapter to handle the JSON. Am heading down the wrong path here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate to the route which is using this route (you may need to familiarize yourself with the router and routes to understand that statement, http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) the json returned by that model hook will be available in the template using standard handlebars syntax `{{property}}`

Here's a simple example, note the naming convention (index template, Index route): http://emberjs.jsbin.com/